# "Do not call .delay on a Sidekiq::Worker class, call .perform_async"

Tags: sidekiq

One pattern I've used often with Sidekiq workers is to define a `perform_all` method:

```
class ModelMutateWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(id)
    model = Model.find(id)
    # Mutate model in some way
  end

  def self.perform_all
    batch = Sidekiq::Batch.new
    batch.description = "#{self.name}.#{__method__}"
    batch.jobs do
      Sidekiq::Client.push_bulk('class' => self, 'args' => Model.ids.map { |id| [id] })
    end
    return batch
  end

end
```

In this somewhat contrived example, the `Model.ids` and `Sidekiq::Client.push_bulk` calls are both somewhat expensive. When performing this action from a web request or the command line, it is preferable to delay those, too.

```
ModelMutateWorker.delay(queue: "my_other_queue").perform_all
```

However, Sidekiq 4.0 [removed](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/242109e872090c1214ff848ea409c3e2de2d994f/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb#L41-L51) `.delay`, `.delay_for`, and `.delay_until` from `Sidekiq::Worker`. I don't remember ever seeing a deprecation warning for this. Is there a DRY way to get this behavior back?

Answer (score 0):

Move `perform_all` into Model or create a new BulkOperation class to hold it.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean a new `BulkOperation` worker, for each former `perform_all` method?

Comment: A simple class which holds that method.  It can take Model as an argument.